# How can I get the "rainbow prompt" in zsh?

Tags: zsh, prompt, zshrc

I love the so-called "rainbow prompt" in bash:

[image]

which I produce thus:

`export PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput setaf 1)\][\[$(tput setaf 3)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\]@\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\h \[$(tput setaf 5)\]\W\[$(tput setaf 1)\]]\[$(tput setaf 7)\]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"`

Unfortunately, that code doesn't work in zsh (which is my main shell).

How can I accomplish the same result in zsh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much simpler in `zsh`, since the shell provides terminal-independent escape sequences for setting the color. For example:

```
PS1='%B[%F{red}%n%F{green}@%F{blue}%m %F{purple}%~] %# %b%f'
```

- `%B`/`%b` - turn bold on/off
- `%F{...}` - set foreground color. You can use color names for the basic colors, or integer indices like `%F{173}` for terminals with larger palettes.
- `%f` - turn off changes to foreground color (i.e., use default color)
- `%n` - user name
- `%m` - hostname up to first `.`
- `%~` - directory name
- `%#` - `#` for root, `%` for normal user (If you still want `$` instead of `%`, this is just a shortcut for the general conditional sequence `%(!.#.%%)`, which you can replace with `%(!.#.$)`, as seen in `man zshmisc`, under Shell state.)

See `man zshmisc`, under "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES" for the full list.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer and the explanation.